# Proving the state of a diode in a clamping circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYF4VT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So i have this positive clamper right here. So the diode will be ON at a negative source voltage since the anode side will see 5V which will be at higher potential than the cathode side, right?

So if the diode is ON, we could replace it with a short circuit. If this is an ideal short circuit, we could say that it has zero voltage across it. But is there a way to do the proving here other than the assumption of an ideal short circuit? We have to prove that the diode is ON and that's the only way i think of how to prove it.

Is it also possible that I could instead prove that it is not OFF, because i could simply do KVL? How would KVL with the assumption that it is ON?

Comment: C1 appears to be shorted

Comment: What if you assume it's open and show that the diode would be forward biased..